# How to use python modules that were renamed 3 in a cross compatible way?

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-3.x

There are several [modules that were renamed in Python 3](http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#othermodules) and I'm looking for a solution that will make your code work in **both** python flavors.

In Python 3, `__builtin__` was renamed to `builtins`. Example:

```
import __builtin__
#...
__builtin__.something # appearing multiple times ("something" may vary)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benjamin Peterson's [six](http://packages.python.org/six/) may be what you are looking for.  Six "provides simple utilities for wrapping over differences between Python 2 and Python 3".  For example:

```
from six.moves import builtin  # works for both python 2 and 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves even more py3 related problems. You could improve the answer a little bit including a small description of this module (just for other readers). Remark: six is very small and it is easy to include it in your package to minimize dependencies.

Comment: Time machine strikes again: I just did.

Comment: This no longer works in six-1.0b1. Try `import six; six.moves.builtin`.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the problem by using nested `try .. except`-blocks:

```
try:
    name = __builtins__.name
except NameError:
    try:
        name = builtins.name
    except NameError:
        name = __buildins__.name
        # if this will fail, the exception will be raised
```

This is no real code, just an example, but `name` will have the proper content, independent from your version. Inside of the blocks you could also `import newname as oldname` or copy the values from the new global `builtins` to the old `__buildin__`:

```
try:
    __builtins__ = builtins
except NameError:
    try:
        __builtins__ = buildins # just for example
    except NameError:
        __builtins__ = __buildins__
        # if this will fail, the exception will be raised
```

Now you can use `__builtins__` just as in previous python-versions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, but "something" may vary. I modified the question to clarify this.